# websocket trigger events in case connection lost between socket client and socket server

Tags: node.js, websocket, express.io

I am using javascript websocket io https://github.com/socketio/socket.io

I have been scratching my head about what event will be triggered on the client and server side in case the connection is lost. Let's say the socket io client running on mobile connects to the socket server over wifi, what events will be triggered if the wifi is down?